# Rails 3.2 Reports based off of Several Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, user-interface, report, reporting

Since this is a Ruby on Rails specific question I hope this belongs here.  I'm designing an inventory system for a warehousing company that has several models such as Product, Client, Shipment, Receipts, etc.

I would like to have a separate reports section that will allow the client to generate reports based off these models, with several reports pulling from many different models.  Here's what the menu will look like:

```
Generate Reports ->
    Shipment Report
    Receipts Report
    Client Report
    Product Report
    Inventory Report
    Billing Report (generates report based off
                    calculations between incoming
                    receipts and outgoing shipments)
```

My question is how to structure the report system in a RESTful way.  Will this consist of simply generating a reports controller corresponding controller methods with views?  Would you generate a reports model?  How would you tackle this problem?

EDIT:
I must add that reports will be generated dynamically with custom date ranges, etc.  Each report will require forms.  My thinking is the view folder could become large if I use one controller .

Comment: What is your driver for wanting the reports to be RESTful?  The answer might help decide quite a few things about your structure/interfacing.

Answer (score 0):

Make each report its own resource (controller) which will only need the new and create actions.

Make a new model class for each report.

Make a class for each form that is used to generate the report.  Here is a good place to encapsulate any data required by the form. It will also be used to store the inputs of the form.

Here is an example :

```
Class ClientReportController < ..

  Def new
    @form = ClientReportForm.new 
  End

  Def create
   @form = ClientReportForm.new params[:form]
   @report = ClientReport.new @form
  End
End
```